# Link_to target '_blank' combined with controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the code:

```
= link_to image_tag(image_info), 'web-site', :target=>'blank'
```

which works great to open the site in a new tab BUT -

The image is an advertisement that I am hosting and I want to also record the fact that the image was clicked and time and other details.

Is there a way to combine the link_to, target '_blank' with a call to a controller action?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with Javascript and to record the click time you need to define an action which will save the time and other details.

```
= link_to image_tag(image_info), 'web-site', class: 'save-time'
```

JS:

```
$('.save-time').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var linkUrl = $(this).attr('href');
  $.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: 'POST'
    success: function(response){
      if(response){
         window.open(linkUrl, '_blank');
      }      
    }
  })    
});
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

One non-Javascript way of going about this would be to create a controller action that:

1. Does whatever tracking you want to do
2. redirects to your external website.

Then set your link up so that it calls your controller action directly.

As a very simple example, that would benefit from a bit more sophistication:

#### Route

```
# config/routes.rb
# [...]
get 'tracking/:url_id', to: 'tracking#redirection', as: 'track_redirection'
```

#### Controller

```
# app/controllers/tracking_controller.rb
class TrackingController

  def redirection
    url = {
      1 => 'google.com',
      2 => 'bbc.com'
    }[params[:url_id]]

    TrackingClass.new(url, current_user).track

    redirect_to url
  end
end
```

#### View

```
= link_to image_tag(image_info), track_redirection_path(1), target: 'blank'
```

This will create an internal link to `/tracking/1` which your controller will then redirect to the correct url.

Answer (score 0):

You can link to the controller method path

```
link_to "controller/method", target: 'blank', method: :post do
  image_tag image_path("whatsapp-icon.svg")
end
```

#### Routes

```
# config/routes.rb    
resources :controller do
  post "method" => "controller#method"
end
```